# Text Extraction based on defined format?

Tags: java, scala, parsing, information-retrieval, rule-engine

1. I have to work on a task where there is a log file provided to me.
2. This logfile is generated from CISCO ASA [Firewall](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/asa-5500-series-next-generation-firewalls/index.html).
3. The log lines look like this: ​​​

   ```
   2013-05-09 11:04:32     Local4.Debug    172.24.100.111 
   %ASA-7-710005: TCP request discarded from 172.17.38.35/63867 to
   inside:172.24.100.111/443 2013-05-09 11:04:32     Local4.Debug   
   172.24.100.111  %ASA-7-609002: Teardown local-host outside:207.46.15.252 duration 0:00:00 2013-05-09 11:04:32    
   Local4.Debug    172.24.100.111  %ASA-7-609001: Built local-host
   outside:64.145.75.27 2013-05-09 11:04:32     Local4.Debug   
   172.24.100.111  %ASA-7-609002: Teardown local-host outside:64.145.75.27 duration 0:00:00 2013-05-09 11:04:32    
   Local4.Debug    172.24.100.111  %ASA-7-609001: Built local-host
   outside:216.156.147.26 2013-05-09 11:04:32     Local4.Debug   
   172.24.100.111  %ASA-7-609002: Teardown local-host outside:216.156.147.26 duration 0:00:00 2013-05-09 11:04:33    
   Local4.Debug    172.24.100.111  %ASA-7-609001: Built local-host
   outside:74.125.224.220 2013-05-09 11:04:33     Local4.Debug   
   172.24.100.111  %ASA-7-609002: Teardown local-host outside:74.125.224.220 duration 0:00:00 2013-05-09 11:04:34    
   Local4.Debug    172.24.100.111  %ASA-7-710005: UDP request discarded
   from 172.24.6.11/68 to inside:255.255.255.255/67
   ```

I looked around and found that these rules are well defined in their [handbook](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/syslog-guide/syslogs.pdf)

**Questions**

1. What the the best way to extract each piece of information based on the rules mentioned in the handbook, rather than running regular expressions and taking value out? I mean can we generate rule based parsing?
2. Given that this is one of the logs, I am sure there would be many log formats supported by many firewalls and they will have their own guidelines as how to read, is there a generic framework that can be built? What framework/library helps you with that?

I am looking for guidance since I don't know much in this area.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried parser combinators?

Comment: "is there a generic framework that can be built" -- if you can write grammars for the different formats, you can use a parser generator to generate parsers, at least.

Comment: @Pyetras, no and don't know what they are, any resources?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, some examples that you can point to?

Comment: @daydreamer See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers and this one http://bitwalker.org/blog/2013/08/10/learn-by-example-scala-parser-combinators/ pretty well explained.

Comment: Since the rules are well defined, it'll we "easy" to write parser for this input so that you get back typed results. I said "easy" because the rules can still be quite complex but if there is no ambiguity then writing a parser with parsers combinators is, IMO, a good way to solve this task.